# css minifier to merge selectors with same properties

Tags: css, compression, minify

I've been using Adobe Reflow to generate layouts. but to my horror, i found that it creates a **separate** selector for **identical** elements too, and each of these selectors have their properties defined *separately*.
This has resulted in enormous file sizes for small documents. I cannot manually merge these selectors due to their enormous size. I've tried several minifiyng programs, but none of them have solved my problem.

in short, need a minifier that can convert:

```
  #div1{ height:50px; color:'blue';}
 #div2{ height:50px; color:'blue';}
```

to

```
 #div1, #div2{ height:50px; color:'blue';}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite online compressor is - http://refresh-sf.com/ it will do the merge for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is best tool based on its description and samples:

CSS minifier with structural optimizations https://css.github.io/csso/csso.html

for example:

```
var result = csso.minifyBlock('color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1); color: #ff0000');

console.log(result.css);
// > color:red
```

Which seems so smart!!

Answer (score 0):

Just ran this code on http://www.cssportal.com/css-optimize/, it worked keeping the default settings. Unfortunately I've never used this before and don't know how it would work on a large CSS file.

Hope that can point you in the right direction.